# Access and modify a 2D array using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, multiprocessing

I'm just starting to work with python multiprocessing.
The problem that I'm facing with my code can be summarized in the following way.

Basically, I am trying to have a 2D array being accessed and modified by several different processes.

I found a similar question here on StackOverflow from a year ago by Alam ([How to create a shared 2D array in python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61880549/how-to-create-a-shared-2d-array-in-python-multiprocessing)) but the answer to the issue was not clearly given.

Here is a code snippet, similar to the one presented by Alam, to help the discussion.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import ctypes as c

n = 2
m = 3

def addData(array, process_number):
    n,m = np.shape(array)
    i=0
    
    for nn in range(n):
        for mm in range(m):
            array[nn][mm] += i
            i=i+1
            
    print("Array after process " + str(process_number))
    print(array)

if __name__=='__main__':

    mp_arr=mp.Array('i', n*m)
    arr = np.frombuffer(mp_arr.get_obj(),c.c_int)

    u = arr.reshape((n, m))
    
    print("Array at the inital state: ")
    print(u)

    p1=mp.Process(target=addData,args=(u,1))
    p2=mp.Process(target=addData,args=(u,2))
    
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    
    print("Array at the final state: ")
    print(u)
```

Here is the output:
[output_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI9kQ.png)

As you can see, the final output of the 2D array is still [[0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
and I would like it to be [[0,2,4], [6, 8, 10]].

Comment: It seems to work for me - when I run it, I get the result ```[[0,2,4], [6, 8, 10]]```. Please specify the OS and version of Python, it may be relevant.

Comment: I'm using python version 3.9.5 on macOS Big Sur version 11.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran this under Windows with Python 3.8.5 I got the same results as you, but under Linux and Python 3.9.7, it worked. Anyway, the following is the technique that seems to work everywhere.

We start off with a `numpy` array, which seems more natural, and from that create a shared memory array and then recreate the `numpy` array using the shared memory as its buffer. The other difference is that we are passing to the processes references to the shared memory and the shape of the `numpy` array and have it recreate the `numpy` array using helper function `to_numpy_array`:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import ctypes as c

n = 2
m = 3

def addData(shared_array, shape, lock, process_number):
    array = to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape)
    n,m = shape
    i=0

    for nn in range(n):
        for mm in range(m):
            with lock:
                array[nn][mm] += i
            i=i+1

    print("Array after process " + str(process_number))
    print(array, flush=True)

def to_shared_array(arr, ctype):
    shared_array = mp.Array(ctype, arr.size, lock=False)
    temp = np.frombuffer(shared_array, dtype=arr.dtype)
    temp[:] = arr.flatten(order='C')
    return shared_array

def to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape):
    '''Create a numpy array backed by a shared memory Array.'''
    arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array)
    return arr.reshape(shape)

if __name__=='__main__':

    # Start with a numpy array!
    mp_arr = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=np.int32)
    shared_array = to_shared_array(mp_arr, c.c_int32)
    # you have to now use the shared array as the base
    u = to_numpy_array(shared_array, mp_arr.shape)

    print("Array at the inital state: ")
    print(u)

    lock = mp.Lock()

    p1=mp.Process(target=addData,args=(shared_array, mp_arr.shape, lock, 1))
    p2=mp.Process(target=addData,args=(shared_array, mp_arr.shape, lock, 2))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print("Array at the final state: ")
    print(u)
```

Prints:

```
Array at the inital state:
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
Array after process 2
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
Array after process 1
[[ 0  2  4]
 [ 6  8 10]]
Array at the final state:
[[ 0  2  4]
 [ 6  8 10]]
```

Comment: Thanks, Booboo. When I run your code, some of the times I get the correct result, but other times I get an incorrect one. Here is the output of the incorrect result:
```Array at the inital state: 
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]

Array after process 1
Array after process 2
[[ 0  1  4]
 [ 6  8 10]][[ 0  1  4]
 [ 6  8 10]]

Array at the final state: 
[[ 0  1  4]
 [ 6  8 10]]```

Does this have anything to do with race conditions?

Comment: Well, you have two tasks executing the `+=` operator, which is not atomic. That is equivalent to `n = array[nn][mm]; n +=1; array[nn][mm] = n`. Create a `multiprocessing.Lock` instance and pass it as an additional argument. See updated answer.

Comment: Both tasks were reading the same value of `n` and therefore incrementing to the same value.

Comment: Does this answer your question?